# Primeng dropdown prevent overlay close on item select and update the options

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I'm trying to update the list of options in dropdown after click the "-More-" option.
I get it work with template for options and binding click event I prevent it stopPropagation() func.

```
<ng-template let-city pTemplate="item">
  <span (click)="onClickFunction(city, $event)">{{city.label}}</span>
</ng-template>

onClickFunction(city, e) {
  if (city.label === '-More-') {
    this.cities.pop();
    this.cities = [...this.cities, ...this.newCities];

    e.stopPropagation();

    this.cd.markForCheck();
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

But the problem is that sometimes it works from the first load, but usally I click 3 times on "-More-" option and then it works correctly.
I this a bug or I'm doing it wrong? maybe there is another better solution?
Thanks

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-demo-j6te3c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem why this sometimes didn't work.

the `<span>` with (click) event binded is way smaller than the box wrapped higher (`<li>`), so when clicked exactly on span this works, if you click a little right to the text option "-More-" than it wouldn't work.

The solution for me is to use `<div>` instead of `<span>` and override the default padding with negative margins and add the exact padding for that

code:

```
<ng-template let-city pTemplate="item">
  <div class="option" (click)="onClickFunction(city, $event)">{{city.label}}</div>
</ng-template>

div.option {
  margin: -0.429em -0.857em;
  padding: 0.429em 0.857em;
}
```